# PreventDefault not working on second click

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I have the following html code:

```
<div>
  <span>Products per page:</span>
  <a class="selectview" href="/womens-clothing/shorts?page=1&view=20">20</a>
  <a class="selectview" href="/womens-clothing/shorts?page=1&view=200">200</a>
<div>
```

and the jQuery is as follows:

```
jQuery('.selectview').click(function (ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();

  var alink = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 

  var view = getLinkVars(alink)["view"]; 
  var page = jQuery("#currentpageno").val();

  alert(alink);
  alert(view);
  alert(page);

  run_ajax(view,page);


});
```

The code runs fine the first time if I click on any of the links; I see the alerts and the ajax code runs fine, but when I click on it the second time, the whole page is refreshed and no alerts are shown.  Then if I click on it again it works, then when I click on it again it works, and so on.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you should post the code for your getLinkVars function aswell? Also check the console for errors, somehow the preventDefault is'nt firing, probably beacuse of some error in your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that `run_ajax` is replacing the links with new ones.  `.click` only binds to the elements that matched the selector at that time.  The newly added links won't have a click event bound to them.

You need to make the events "live".  Bind them using [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like so:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.selectview', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // code...
});
```

This will "delegate" the event.  It will run for all `.selectview` links no matter when they are added to the DOM.

Comment: Just as easily is the more commonly used syntax `.live('click', function(ev) {})` rather than the slightly less popular `.on` syntax. Essentially having to do dynamic binding to the click event rather than static binding will work here.

Comment: @Mattygabe: `.live` was commonly used *before* jQuery 1.7.  In jQuery 1.7+, `.live`, as well as `.bind` and `.delegate` are deprecated.  jQuery suggests you use `.on` for all your event binding needs.  `.on` should be more "popular" once people upgrade their code.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you very much, that was doing my head in :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat I know this is a old question, but maybe you can help? I have table with clickable tr `<tr onclick="redirect()">` 
and inside its td i have button that on click do some action. .. 
https://jsfiddle.net/master1991/12nyxh8j/4/ issue is that if i use `$(document).on('click', '.moveTo',` it does `<tr>` redirect but if i use `$('.moveTo').on('click',` it work on page load but it does n0t work dynamically.
What could be the issue?

Comment: When you do `$(document).on('click', '.moveTo',` the event is actually bound to the `document`.  Then whenever you click, it checks whether that click was on a `.moveTo` element or not.

Answer (score 0):

If run_ajax is replacing the links you can wrap the code that attaches your click handlers, and then inside run_ajax you can call the wrapper after you've replaced the links with the new content:

```
var setupClickHandlers = function(container) {
    jQuery(container).find('.selectview').click(function (ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        var alink = jQuery(this).attr('href'); 

        var view = getLinkVars(alink)["view"]; 
        var page = jQuery("#currentpageno").val();

        alert(alink);
        alert(view);
        alert(page);

        run_ajax(view,page);
    });
};
setupClickHandlers(container);
```

The in run_ajax:

```
var run_ajax = function(view, page) {
    // do your stuff here

    // set up click handlers on the new content
    setupClickHandlers(container);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I used Mattygabe's solution and that worked perfectly.  Thanks :)

Comment: Ooops I meant Rocket's answer :)